# Lua Networking - Passing data through a 'closed' port

Tags: sockets, networking, lua, udp, port

This might be a bit weird to explain, but I'll try my best.

I have a Lua program that's intended to serve some data through the network. Specifically, the internet. The data the program is actually transmitting are only strings stored within UDP packets. Generalized, this is how the program operates:

1. The first client launches the program and specifies that they are the 'host' of the connection. The program opens a connection on UDP port 6000 and the main loop listens for any packets received on said port.
2. The second client launches the program and specifies that they are to connect to the 'host' on port 6000. The user enters the IP, and the client opens a UDP connection using a random port between 6050 and 7000
3. When the client successfully connects to the server, they send a 'connection' packet, simply containing a '202 OK' string. The 'host' receives this and registers the new client
4. Now that the connection has been initialized, the programs can send data between each other using the registered data.

Now, on a local network this program works fine. The purpose of the 'host' mode is to have multiple clients connect to the host and have the host relay packets from one clients to all the currently registered clients. Port selections are arbitrary and random port selection from the client was simply to allow debugging and testing from a single computer. This has been tested between two and more computers on a physical network, and worked successfully. However, when I attempt to run this over the internet it's a no go. I know that the ports are closed and that's why it's not working. But seeing as I'm going to be distributing this program (privately) I can't expect every person to open ports on their router (or know how to). Security is not currently a concern with the program, and should be disregarded in the current state. That being said, I recognise there's the potential for a lot to go wrong with the use of this program through the network and I accept that. Onto the main question, how can I have the host and client communicate over the internet without having to open ports?

I'll elaborate - for example, browsers. Although the technology is quite different to what I'm doing, it's easier to paint a picture - the browser requests data from a web server, and it gets sent back to the client. But wait, if the router is in it's default state (I hope) all the ports are closed? So how does the client receive this data if the port is closed?

I hope this makes some kind of sense and I don't sound like a complete fool.

Comment: Read about stun/turn. Also you can read about how SIP registers works with NAT. SIP uses mechanism that you describe. Client send register and server response 200 ok.

Comment: You have stumbled into a non-trivial problem.  It is not uncommon, however, for the "host" to be required to open a port, as evidenced by sites like [this one](http://portforward.com).  For every alternate workaround, you are still likely to find cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: I did think about just opening the port for the host, but I haven't yet tried that Michael-sqlbot. I think I might opt for using stun/turn as @moteus suggested - I've been looking at a couple FAQs and things about it, and it looks like the way to go for what I'm after. The biggest challenge I'll have from here on in is finding/making an implementation in LUA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find some suitable libraries and utilities to be able to communicate through the internet (NAT traversal is now a term I am familiar with), those libraries being that supplied by [NMAP](https://nmap.org/book/nse-library.html). These libraries include an implementation for STUN in LUA, among HEAPS of other useful networking-related libraries and scripts.

To actually answer my own question (very simply), the clients and servers are behind what's known as a NAT gateway. Due to the limitations of addresses of IPv4, NAT gateways were implemented to bypass this limitation of IPv4 (a total of about 4.2 billion addresses) by separating the clients' internal network from the external network - in this case the internet. The NAT is supplied with a single IP address, and the NAT then supplies all of its users within the internal network with an IP respective to the network they're on. As such, the devices cannot directly be accessed without forwarding connections from the NAT gateway (generally the router) to the client. However, when using UDP connections the NAT gateway opens a port for the purposes of this connection which gets closed after the connection dies. This port that is opened differs from what is specified by the client when they open the connection, which is where the STUN methods come in. STUN allows the host to find the port that the client is connecting from and send data back to this port so the user can receive it. Bear in mind this is an EXTREMELY simple explanation of how the technology works, and I'd suggest reading up on the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) and some of the [Request for Comments](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3489.txt) for STUN.